# Clustering Force Layout

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, cluster-analysis

I'm currently working on a variation of a clustered force layout uses D3’s circle-packing layout to initialize node positions.

You can find the original code at : [ClusterForce Layout IV](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7882658)

However I can't find a way to choose the number of nodes per cluster.
For example: For a number of nodes equal to 20 (n=20), I'd like to have my 10 clusters (m=10) shared like 2 nodes each.

I tried a lot of changes using the "d3.nest()" part, but nothing worked like I wanted to.

If someone could help , thakns a lot !